# Why does personNameComponents return an incorrect familyName based on the middle name?

Tags: swift, foundation

In some cases `personNameComponents` is returning an incorrect family name.

Here is a playground example:

```swift
import UIKit

var name = "John Marty Johnson"
let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
var nameComponents = formatter.personNameComponents(from: name)
print(nameComponents)
```

Which returns the following when run:

```swift
Optional(givenName: John familyName: Marty Johnson )
```

It should return familyName: Johnson.

If I change the middle name to "Michael" it works as expected.

I've also tried the following code, which also fails:

```swift
var name = "John Marty Johnson"
let nameComponents = try PersonNameComponents(name)

print(nameComponents)
```

This is not the only middle name that fails.

I am using Swift version 5.5.2 and later.

Has anyone run into this and do you have a solution?

Comment: From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/personnamecomponentsformatter/1642979-personnamecomponents): "This method uses a combination of locale rules and heuristics to determine the most likely name components for a particular string representation." There is no unambiguous way to know how to split up a name in a vaccuum: "Marty Johnson" _could_ be someone's last name, as could their first name be "John Marty". Looks like this is a case where the heuristics are giving a result you're not expecting.

Comment: The link to the docs above lays out some of the heuristics used to try to determine what name component each substring is. If you only have access to the name as a singular string, then there isn't much you can do. Theoretically, you could pass the name in as a differently-formatted string to help the heuristics along, but that would likely require getting the original info in multiple pieces, which would likely sidestep the need for parsing a name like this altogether.

Answer (score -1):

You're creating a `PersonNameComponentsFormatter` when using `let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()`

When using `var nameComponents = formatter.personNameComponents(from: name)` you are creating a `PersonNameComponents` object, you are not specifying what to print from this, which is why it is printing

```swift
Optional(givenName: John familyName: Marty Johnson )
```

If your goal is to only print the family name, you would need to do:

```swift
print(nameComponents?.familyName)
```

Note the `?` because `nameComponents` is optional

**Whole code:**

```swift
var name = "John Marty Johnson"
let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
var nameComponents = formatter.personNameComponents(from: name)
print(nameComponents)

print(nameComponents?.familyName)
```

Returns:

```swift
Optional(givenName: John familyName: Marty Johnson )
Optional("Marty Johnson")
```